# SQL: Calculating if an ID does NOT appear that did appear in the previous week only

Tags: mysql, sql, join, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm trying to figure out, on a rolling week-by-week basis, if a user attended or did not attend an event. However, I only want to include them as "did not attend" **if they attended the previous week**. For example if user attends Week 1 and Week 7, they would be only counted as "did not attend" for Weeks 2 and 8.

A simplified example of the data:

Table **events** which includes all event dates (weekly) and a unique event ID (time ascending)

| Event_Date | Event_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-09 | 1 |
| 2023-03-16 | 2 |
| 2023-03-23 | 3 |

And table **users** which shows the event dates and ID they attended:

| Event_Date | Event_ID | User_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-09 | 1 | 151 |
| 2023-03-16 | 2 | 151 |
| 2023-03-23 | 3 | 151 |
| 2023-03-09 | 1 | 299 |
| 2023-03-23 | 3 | 299 |
| 2023-03-16 | 2 | 373 |

My question: How can I accomplish the following output using SQL? (User 299 attended Event 1 but not 2; User 373 attended Event 2 but not 3)

| Missed_Event_Date | Missed_Event_ID | User_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-16 | 2 | 299 |
| 2023-03-23 | 3 | 373 |

I have tried using

```
SELECT      Event_ID + 1,
            User_ID
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM events WHERE u.Event_ID=e.Event_ID + 1)
```

which did not produce the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Event_ID` increases by one, you might consider below as well.

```sql
SELECT u.Event_ID + 1 AS Missed_Event_ID, u.User_ID
  FROM users u LEFT JOIN users v 
    ON u.User_ID = v.User_ID AND u.Event_ID + 1 = v.Event_ID
 WHERE v.Event_ID IS NULL AND u.Event_ID < (SELECT MAX(Event_ID) FROM events);

-- Query results
+-----------------+---------+
| Missed_Event_ID | User_ID |
+-----------------+---------+
|               2 |     299 |
|               3 |     373 |
+-----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This worked right away, and not too many lines which is great!

Comment: Great, I was trying the same and I missed u.Event_ID + 1;
Good Solution, +1